# Keycloak logout response 414

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus, logout

```
GET /realms/[REALM_NAME]/protocol/openid-connect/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=[...]&id_token_hint=[..very large jwt-token >4096..]
```

- Response `414` (Uri to long ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414%5D))
- Keycloak version: v20.0.1
- Expected: Successful logout redirect. The above request should response `302`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the logout URI path is to long. The default length of the keycloak quarkus service is 4096 bytes ([link](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.limits.max-initial-line-length)).

- this occur when Your id_token_hint is to large

Set higher length for quarkus parameter **quarkus.http.limits.max-initial-line-length** ...

- as java parameter `-quarkus.http.limits.max-initial-line-length=8192`
- or environment variable `QUARKUS_HTTP_LIMITS_MAX_INITIAL_LINE_LENGTH=8192`

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing and id_token to the id_token_hint instead of the access token?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you should pass an *ID token* to the `id_token_hint` and not and *access token*. From the [OpenID Connect standard](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) (section 2.RP-Initiated Logout) one can read:

> This specification defines the following parameters that are used in
> the logout request at the Logout Endpoint:
>
> **id_token_hint** RECOMMENDED. **ID Token previously** issued by the OP to the
> RP passed to the Logout Endpoint as a hint about the End-User's
> current authenticated session with the Client. This is used as an
> indication of the identity of the End-User that the RP is requesting
> be logged out by the OP.

So you need to pass `id_token_hint=<id_token>`. You get the *ID token* by calling the token endpoint with the `scope=openid`. For example, when a user logs in via browser if you request includes the `scope=openid` you will get (along with the *refresh* and *access tokens*) the user *ID token*.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, this was due to extra claims we added with custom mappers. The solution was to only add those extra claims to the access token, not the id token.

This can be done in the mapper settings by setting 'Add to ID token' to 'Off' for your custom mapper.

[image: Screenshot of of Keycloak mapper settings]

Comment: See https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/ for a good overview of the difference between id token and access token.